# How to mark only product categories?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

How do I have to mark my website product categories? … only categories …

Maybe with `category` from `Offer`?

Something like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
   <a itemprop="category" href="category1.php">My category 1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not specify `category` on an `a` element. The [value would be the URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669) (`category1.php`), not the content (`My category 1`).

[`category`](http://schema.org/category) expects a value that is either text or another item.

So if you want to provide text, you could use something like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
   <a href="category1.php"><span itemprop="category">My category 1</span></a>
</div>
```

And yes, it is totally fine to use only one property. [Schema.org doesn’t define required properties](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58912/17633). But consumers (e.g., search engines) might, of course, only consider re-using your data if it fulfils certain of their own requirements.

---

UPDATE: If you want to provide several categories for the item, it could be something like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <ul>
   <li itemprop="category"><a href="category1.php">My category 1</a></li>
   <li itemprop="category"><a href="category2.php">My category 2</a></li>
   <li itemprop="category"><a href="category3.php">My category 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Don’t rename the `category` property! Adding `1`, `2` etc. to it would be wrong.

(And it it’s a hierarchy of categories, you could use one value and `/` or `>`., e.g. `Sports > Tennis`.)

Comment: ok @unor, but if i have many categories must put different itemscope to make  that or put all into only itemscope block? like...  `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><span itemprop="category1">My category 1</span><span itemprop="category2">My category 2</span><span itemprop="category3">My category 3</span>
</div>`

Comment: @mdromed: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Ok perfect @unor.  Then ([in my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990049/2-itemprops-for-2-colors-of-the-same-product)) with `color` itemprops would be the same?  And...Is it valid in Google testing tool, repeating itemprop items?

Comment: @mdromed: It’s valid Microdata. Google would probably understand it, too. But if they like it or not (i.e., if or how they re-use your markup) is a SEO question which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mdromed: You’re welcome. Two more meta things: **a)** When commenting, the `@username` part must be the first thing in your comment, otherwise it would not notify the person in all cases. **b)** You may accept my answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: @mdromed: I know, you need at least 15 reputation to vote. But you can still accept my answer (by clicking at the checkmark below the voting buttons).