# Is the "content" attribute valid for the <span> tag > if so is it a good practice?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

Is the "content" attribute valid for `span` tag? If so is it a good practice? 
I'll be applying microdata (schema.org) on my site pages.

I want to add microdata on some elements of my page.

This is my current code:

```
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <a itemprop="url" class="list-items" href="/product/286/cryptomate64-usb-cryptographic-token/" title="CryptoMate64 USB Cryptographic Token">
            <span itemprop="name">CryptoMate64 USB Cryptographic Token</span>
            <span class="hidden">
                <span itemprop="productid"/>286</span>
                <span itemprop="model" content="ACOS5T-B2-SCZ" />ACOS5T-B2-SCZ</span>
            </span>
        </a>    
    </span>
```

As you can see, I have a `div` with class "hidden" there because the model and id shouldn't be displayed on the page.

I want to minify the code by doing this:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <a itemprop="url" class="list-items" href="/product/286/cryptomate64-usb-cryptographic-token/" title="CryptoMate64 USB Cryptographic Token">
        <span itemprop="name">CryptoMate64 USB Cryptographic Token</span>
        <span itemprop="productid" content="286" />&nbsp;</span>
        <span itemprop="model" content="ACOS5T-B2-SCZ" />&nbsp;</span>
    </a>    
</span>
```

I can use `meta` instead of `span` so that the content is not visible. But I think it won't be a good practice since I'll be having a lot of items. What can you suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your updated code with [Google's richsnippets test tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and it works fine with the `content` attribute on the `span`.

However, this isn't good practice since there is no content inside the last 2 spans anyway. It is perfectly appropriate in this case to use **metas**.

```
<meta itemprop="productid" content="286">
<meta itemprop="model" content="ACOS5T-B2-SCZ">
```

Comment: say i have 15 items, there will be lot of _meta_ tags, i think google would consider it as inappropriate and overused.

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s **not valid**.

Neither HTML5 nor Microdata define a `content` attribute for `span`. ([RDFa does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898363/1591669), but you are not using it.)

If you want to markup content with Microdata that should not be visible, either

- use usual HTML and hide it with CSS, or
- use `link` elements (for URIs) and `meta` elements (for anything else); both elements are [allowed in the `body`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669), and typically hidden by default browser stylesheets.

I’d prefer the latter variant (`meta`/`link`), but it’s not possible everytime (e.g., if you need to add new items with `itemscope`).

Comment: i can wrap the new _itemscope_ in a _span_ tag, but i think, since there will be a lot of products, using _meta_ will be considered by google as inapropriate?

Comment: @user3909562: Of course it would be better to mark up visible content, but as you don’t want to do that, you have the mentioned options. Note that discussing such SEO-related rules from specific consumers (like Google) is off-topic on Stack Overflow; but it’s safe to assume that hiding content via CSS (instead of using `meta`/`link`) would be more problematic than using the appropriate mechanism specified in Microdata and also mentioned on Schema.org: using `meta`/`link` for invisible content.

Comment: yes, i think using meta would be better. Thanks @unor