# schema.org product availability tags markup

Tags: html, semantic-markup, schema.org, microdata

Which one is correct?

```html
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
​<meta itemprop="availability" content="InStock" />
<span itemprop="availability" content="in_stock"></span>
```

I checked official schema documentation and in examples found all of them.

I suppose all of them will work, but at the moment, is there any preferred standard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `span` with the `content` attribute is **invalid**. [Neither HTML5 nor Microdata allow the `content` attribute for `span`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898363/1591669).

Using `meta` is **invalid**. HTML5 and Microdata require that [`meta` must not be used for URI values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669).

Using `link` is correct. It’s also used in [Schema.org’s enumeration guide](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_enum). If some examples use `meta` instead, we may expect these to be [fixed](https://github.com/rvguha/schemaorg/issues/77).

Answer (score 2):

```
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
```

is probably best since it most closely adheres to the Enumeration that is https://schema.org/ItemAvailability.

I wouldn't use the 3rd example (`<span itemprop="availability" content="in_stock"></span>`) because `in_stock` may not map exactly to the values listed.