# How to add an image to an event with Microdata meta tag?

Tags: html, microdata

Using microdata, is there a way to add an image into an Event by using a meta tag?

In the official Microdata site I see the option of adding images to events:

```
<img itemprop="image" src="image.jpg" alt="An image"/>
```

which works fine. However, I wonder if it is possible to add that image by using something like:

```
<meta itemprop="image" src="image.jpg"  />
```

which according to my tests does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the `meta` element, you must use the `link` element (because the value is a URI):

```html
<link itemprop="image" href="image.jpg" />
```

This is [required by HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) (bold emphasis mine):

> The `meta` element represents various kinds of metadata that **cannot be expressed using the […] `link` […] elements**.

And it’s also explicitly [required by Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728910/1591669).

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer myself. For the record, meta tags must specify their value with the *content* attribute:

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="image.jpg"  />
```