# VideoObject rich snippets don't appear in search results

Tags: video, seo, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have allready done a LOT off research on this topic but I can't seem to figure it out, I've tried about everything there is to try to get my video snippets in the google search results, but no go. 
I used all the correct schema.org mark-up and also working with a video xml sitemap. There's only one video on the page that I'm trying to get the snippet from, and I'm testing it with the tool provided by google. My page is fully validated.

Here is the code for my video object:

```
<div id="Platenstelling-horizontaal" class="columns cols-8"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
<h2>Video:<span itemprop="name"> Handeling metalen platen in de platenstelling horizontaal<span></h2>
<meta itemprop="thumbnailURL" content="http://www.eurostorage.be/_styles/_assets/movies/platenstelling_horizontaal/horizontaal1_thumb.JPG">
<meta itemprop="duration" content="T50S">
<meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2013-11-13" />
<meta itemprop="contentUrl" content="//jwpsrv.com/feed/1VAJvmIw.rss" />
<span itemprop="description">In deze 3D-video ziet u de opslag en handeling van metalen platen in de platenstelling horizontaal.</span>
<div id='player1VAJvmIw'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('player1VAJvmIw').setup({
    playlist: '//jwpsrv.com/feed/1VAJvmIw.rss',
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: '16:9',
    primary: 'flash'
});
</script>
</div>
```

I would be supergratefull if somebody could point me in the right direction since i've been stuck on this topic for quite some time now.

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, but note that you [must use `link` instead of `meta` when the value is a URI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669).

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why google doesn't index your page as a video result.
I recommend you to follow google guidelines to markup your videos.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2413309?hl=en

Your contentUrl leads to rss instead mp4 file:

```
<meta itemprop="contentUrl" content="//jwpsrv.com/feed/1VAJvmIw.rss" />
```

This is google recommendation:

A URL pointing to the actual video media file. This file should be in .mpg, .mpeg, .mp4, .m4v, .mov, .wmv, .asf, .avi, .ra, .ram, .rm, .flv, or other video file format. All files must be accessible via HTTP. Metafiles that require a download of the source via streaming protocols, such as RTMP, are not supported.
Providing this file allows Google to generate video thumbnails and video previews and can help Google verify your video.

From my experience  googlebot checks some factors to ensure your markup is valid and indeed there is a video in your markup. this process doesn't fast as google index youtube videos..

Comment: Tnx for the answer, but I've tried everything according to google's guidelines, and now I'm streaming via an rss, but I used to do it with an mp4, and even then, no go...

Comment: your videos is hidden by tabs, maybe this is the reason why google doesn't index that pages as video result.

Comment: Do you have a link as well?

Comment: also tried allready to unhide the video content, when i'm testing it with the tool still no video :-(

@EthanJWPlayer
http://www.eurostorage.be/opslag-metalen-platen/platenstelling-horizontaal-b.php

Comment: What if you made the first tab the video instead?

Answer (score 0):

Google has reduced the % of video snippets appearing on organic search and that can be the possible reason in your case even if markups are technically correct-

Please refer below articles, those will clear few things-

http://boldcontentvideo.com/2014/08/12/google-reduces-video-rich-snippets/
http://www.blindfiveyearold.com/the-rich-snippets-algorithm

Hope this helps!