# Is this structured data markup using schema.org for a game review correct?

Tags: html, schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data

I understand that it takes time for Google to show rich snippets for a website. But, I want to make sure that I'm marking up my structured data correctly in the mean time. Is the following code okay for a review? Can it be done better?

```
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <meta itemprop="inLanguage" content="en-CA">
    <article itemprop="reviewBody">
        <header>
            <img itemprop="thumbnailUrl" src="/review/pushmo.jpg" alt="Pushmo">
            <h1 itemprop="name"><span itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing"><span itemprop="name">Pushmo</span></span> Review</h1>
            <h2 itemprop="headline">This sumo wrestling cat has children to rescue</h2>
            <p>Reviewed by <a href="/profile/crazyaj" rel="author" itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">A.J. Maciejewski</span><meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com/profile/crazyaj"></a> on <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-09-03T20:33:03-07:00">September 3, 2014</time></p>
            <meta itemprop="description" content="Review for Pushmo on 3DS. This sumo wrestling cat has children to rescue. Pushmo proves that Nintendo still has the ability to produce great new properties.">
            <meta itemprop="keywords" content="Review,3DS,Pushmo">
        </header>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
            <span itemprop="ratingValue">8.4</span> <small>out of <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1"><span itemprop="bestRating">10</span></small>
        </div>
    </article>
</main>
```

As a side note, I noticed when I search for "review site:example.com" the rich snippets appear but they don't when I don't use "site:example.com". Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks again for reading. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that your side question about Google’s search is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the following points, your use of HTML5, Microdata and schema.org looks good to me.

- When the value is a URL, you [must use `link` instead of `meta`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669). So it should be

  ```
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/profile/crazyaj">
  ```
- As value for [`itemReviewed`](http://schema.org/itemReviewed), you might want to use a more specific type than [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing). For *Pushmo*, it would be [`SoftwareApplication`](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) (the subtype `VideoGame` will probably be added soon, it’s already proposed and discussed).
- You should not use `h2` for a subtitle. This was possible with the `hgroup` element, but as `hgroup` is no longer part of HTML5, this would now create a wrong document outline. [Instead, simply use a `div`/`p` for the subtitle](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/68608/17633).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very informative answer and I will follow all of your points.