# Validation error: "The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item"

Tags: seo, meta-tags, w3c-validation, schema.org, microdata

For better SEO I need put some meta on my page like this:

```html
<!-- Schema.org markup for Google+ -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="The Name or Title Here">
<meta itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
```

[Here is the source](http://moz.com/blog/meta-data-templates-123).

Then I check this code on [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="The Name or Title Here">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
  My body.
</body>
</html>
```

Throwing this error:

> Line 4, Column 57: The `itemprop` attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.
>
> ```html
>  <meta itemprop="name" content="The Name or Title Here">
> ```
>
> Line 5, Column 70: The `itemprop` attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.
>
> ```html
>  <meta itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
> ```
>
> Line 6, Column 68: The `itemprop` attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.
>
> ```html
>  <meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
> ```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that you [must use the `link` element (instead of `meta`) if the value is a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669). So your third `meta` element  should be this instead: `<link itemprop="image" href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should explicitly provide a *type* these properties (`name`, `description`, `image`) belong to.

In Schema.org, everything is a [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing). `Thing` has many child types, listed under "More specific Types". Start there and choose the most specific type for your content.

For example: [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage), [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) or maybe [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting).

It could look like (using `WebPage` as example here):

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. and please share how to add country code and postal address using schema in web page

Comment: @JomalJohny: This wouldn’t be the right place here. If you have a problem implementing it, please ask a question and describe the problem in detail.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `itemprop` meta tag in `header` for your site title, description and so on.

only just add `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"` in your `html tag`.

Usage:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
```