# Itemprop errors

Tags: html, wordpress

I checked my blog-article' page on validator.w3.org and it keeps show this errors:

**Error 1**:

```
The **itemprop** attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.
```

My blog code:

```
<h1 class="blogtitle entry-title" itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">↩
<span itemprop="name">The article title</span>↩
</h1>
```

**Error 2**:

```
The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.
```

The code:

```
<h1 class="blogtitle entry-title" itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">↩
<span itemprop="title">Article title</span>
</h1>
```

So in that code I have 2 itemprop errors.

Then **Error 3**:

```
The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.
```

The code:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/author/Siteauthors"  itemprop="author" target="_blank"><span class="vcard author author_name"><span class="fn">Siteauthors</span></span></a>
```

So How Can I solve this errors? I want my page to have no errors, and only these errors still! I read some articles about this "itemtrop" but I didn't understand much!

Any help is welcome!!!!!

Comment: Can you give the entire markup of your page that is not validating properly in a gist? (Please don't post it entirely in the question body.)

Comment: First, thank you @michaelrmcneill so much for your replay, second, although I read many articles about markups yesterday, I feel like they are beyond me, but I still want to implement them if they are worth (for SEO). So, among these articles, I find [this](http://www.bloggingspell.com/add-schema-org-markup-wordpress) (please note it is not an advertising) and there, the author detailed "how to add markups to wordpress blog"

Comment: but they are too many. So, my question is, do I follow him? I mean, I must go to implement all of them? Or maybe just some little of them? Or? .....Can you please enlighten me!!!

Comment: For me to help you, I need the entire markup of your page that is not validating properly. Please provide that and I will attempt to assist you further.

Comment: ok... this is the [link](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cosmosup.com%2Fnasa-hubble-makemake-moon%2F&showsource=yes)

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted an answer that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly provide a property (and a type for the property). To do so, you need to add an `itemtype` to your `<html>` tag.

In your specific instance, you need to change:

`<html lang="en-US">`

to:

`<html lang="en-US" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">`

And it will successfully validate.

In Schema.org, everything is a [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing). [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing) has many child types, listed under "More specific Types". Start there and choose the most specific type for your content. In this example, I chose [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage), but you could choose any type.

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29124838/836695

Comment: Thank you so much ... its worked hurahhhh :) .... So I solved the problem but I still have one question, what about all these itemprops from that article? Is it enough what I'd added to my website? Or I must add the others itemprops? Thank you again

Comment: You do not have to add the other itemprops.