# How can I nest <meta> tags for Microdata?

Tags: html, meta, schema.org, microdata

I've this kind of structure:

```
+ EVENT -> itemtype="http://schema.org/Event
 + Name   
 + Date   
 + ...
 + LOCATION -> itemtype="http://schema.org/Place
        *          Name
     + Url
     + ...
```

I won't show all the Place information on the website, but I want to use the information for Microdata.
And so I want to add this tag:

```html
<meta itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
```

Works fine.

But how can I add the itemprops for `name`, `url`, "address" for `location`?

It won't works like :

```html
<meta itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://example-location.com">
<meta itemprop="name" content="exampleLocationName">
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please take a moment to review our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723346/specifying-complex-structure-with-meta-tag-in-microdata.

Answer (score 4):

Probably like this. Actually unsure of it.

```html
<meta itemprop="location" content="" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" itemref="place-url place-name">
<link id="place-url" itemprop="url" href="https://example-location.com">
<meta id="place-name" itemprop="name" content="exampleLocationName">
```

---

### Can’t you just ditch the ugly empty `content`?

> #### https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata#x7-2-content-models
>
> If a `meta` element has an `itemprop` attribute, the `name`, `http-equiv`, and `charset` attributes must be omitted, and the `content` attribute must be present.

You can’t.

### Why `<link>` instead of `<meta>`?

Because only *URL property elements* can have an *absolute URL* as their values, and `<link>` is one while `<meta>` is not.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata#x5-4-values-the-content-attribute-element-specific-attributes-and-element-content:

> The ***algorithm to determine the value for a name-value pair*** is given by
>   applying the first matching case in the following list:
>
> - If the element also has an `itemscope` attribute: the value is the item
>     created by the element.
> - If the element has a `content` attribute: the value is the `textContent` of
>     the element’s `content` attribute.

> The ***URL property elements*** are the `a`, `area`, `audio`, `embed`, `iframe`, `img`, `link`, `object`, `source`, `track`, and `video` elements.

> If a property’s *value*, as defined by the property’s definition, is an *absolute URL*, the property must be specified using a *URL property element*.

### How about nesting `<meta>` tags?

You cannot, as the `<meta>` is a *void element*, which must not have any children.

---

## Better yet

Have you considered [using JSON-LD](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the event microdata inside the Event entity. In your specific case:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Name</h1>
    <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2018-07-28T20:23:16+02:00" content="2018-07-28T20:23:16+02:00">28 luglio 2018</time>
    ...
    <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Place">
        <h2>Location: <span itemprop="name">Location Name</span></h2>
        <meta itemprop="url" content="https://example-location.com">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to hide all the location informations, you can act as above but hide the whole Event entity:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    ...
    <div style='display: none;' itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Place">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Location Name">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="https://example-location.com">
    </div>
</div>
```