# Write Microdata just with <link> and <meta>

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

How to write this Microdata code

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.6</span> (
    <span itemprop="ratingCount">8864</span> ratings )
  </div>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    Price: $<span itemprop="price">1.00</span>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
  </div>
```

as `<link …>` or `<meta …>`? I do not have HTML tag in my page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value is a URI, [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) `link`. Otherwise, use `meta`.

So `<span itemprop="ratingValue">4.6</span>` becomes `<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.6" />` etc.

If it’s just about having no visible content, you could keep using the parent `div` elements, e.g.:

```html
<div itemscope> <!-- you can/should give it an itemtype -->

  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.6" />
    <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="8864" />
  </div>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="1.00" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
  </div>

</div>
```

If you also want to omit these `div` elements, you’d have to use the `itemref` attribute, because you can’t nest elements under `link`/`meta`. And because `meta` elements used for Microdata [require the `itemprop` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669), you *have* to use one parent element (e.g., `div`, `body`, `html`) to specify an `itemscope`:

```html
<body itemscope> <!-- you can/should give it an itemtype -->

  <meta itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" content="" itemref="my-rv my-rc">
  <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.6" id="my-rv" />
  <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="8864" id="my-rc" />

</body>
```

Having said that, if you generally don’t want to markup your existing/visible content, you might want to use JSON-LD instead of Microdata or RDFa.

Comment: Thanks unor I underestand  most  of these type of question only you answer