# What image quality to use for Google Rich Snippets?

Tags: image, schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I know for Google Shopping (or whatever it's called now) it's recommended providing the URL to the highest quality image there is for the product.  Does that same principal apply for Product rich snippets?

Although it's rendered on the product page, I can easily provide the URL to the high-res image like this:

```html
<meta itemprop="image" content="/img/high-res.jpg"></meta>
```

Or I can just tag `itemprop="image"` to one of the lower quality images that is shown on the website?  But it's only 400 x 400px, compared to high-res which is 2000 x 2000px.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some Rich Snippets (including the Product Rich Snippet), Google does not recommend any image dimensions, for others, they specify

> at least 160x90 pixels and at most 1920x1080 pixels

([taken from my answer on Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82033/17633))

If you want to provide an image URL without showing the image, you [must use `link` instead of `meta`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669):

```html
<link itemprop="image" href="/img/high-res.jpg" />
```

(Side note: The `meta` element has no closing tag `</meta>`.)

Comment: Thanks unor, I've switched to a lower res image to be safe.  Also, yes just realised the error of using <meta so I've now switched to <link