# Getting correct schema to fix "The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item."

Tags: html, meta-tags, schema.org, w3c-validation, microdata

I am trying to get these meta tags to work with social media but I keep getting an error from the W3C validator:

> The `itemprop` attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.

I tried putting `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Products` but that just made more errors. Here's my HTML source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <meta name="language" content="english"> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="'.$keywords.'">

    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="'.$meta_image.'"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="'.$meta_url.'" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="'.$meta_name.'"/> 
    <meta property="og:description" name="description" content="'.$description.'" />    
    <meta property="og:title" content="'.$title.'"/>

    <meta itemprop="name" content="'.$title.'">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="'.$description.'">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="'.$meta_image.'">
    <!-- … -->
```

What is wrong with my tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an `html` element with an `itemscope` attribute, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    …
    <meta itemprop="name" content="'.$title.'">
    …
```

Incidentally you can also just omit the `head` start tag, and you should always specify a `title` in every HTML document; so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Products</title>
  …
  <meta itemprop="name" content="'.$title.'">
  …
```

The reason you need the `itemscope` attribute is because **the `itemscope` attribute is what actually *creates* the item**.

In other words, **without `itemscope`, you don’t actually have an item**—instead, you just have a bunch of properties that aren’t associated with anything.

And by specifying the `itemscope` attribute on the `html` element, what the document is saying is, basically something like, *The scope of the properties specified here is the entire document.*, or *The properties specified here apply to the entire document.*,

Answer (score 3):

[Like sideshowbarker explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32487005/1591669), every `itemprop` needs an item (created by an `itemscope`) that it belongs to.

But if you intend to use a vocabulary (like Schema.org), you should also add an `itemtype` in addition to the `itemscope`. The `itemtype` attribute gives the type (from a vocabulary) of the item (= `itemscope`) to which you apply the properties (= `itemprop`).

You said you tried to add the type `http://schema.org/Products`, but this one does not exist. If you mean [`http://schema.org/Product`](http://schema.org/Product) instead, you could add the following to your `html` or `head` element:

```html
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="'.$title.'">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="'.$description.'">
  <link itemprop="image" href="'.$meta_image.'">
</head>
```

(Note that you [must use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) the `link` element instead of the `meta` element if the value is a URI; I changed it accordingly for the `image` property.)