# What could cause the Twitter card validator to give a redirect loop error?

Tags: twitter, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph, rdfa, twitter-card

I'm using https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator on `http://parlaywith.me`.

When I include this tag (currently included):

```html
<meta property="og:url"
       content="http://parlaywith.me">
```

I get this error:

> [image: ERROR: Fetching the page failed because it resulted in too many redirects. WARN: this card is redirected to http://parlaywith.me/]

When I remove the tag, I get:

> [image: INFO: Page fetched successfully]

How can I keep the `og:url` tag and avoid the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have to specify the URL with the trailing slash:

```
http://parlaywith.me/
```

instead of

```
http://parlaywith.me
```

Also note that HTML5 [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) to use `link` (instead of `meta`) if the value is a URI:

```html
<link property="og:url"
    href="http://parlaywith.me/">
```