# Google SDTT appending "#__sid=md3" to URL for mainEntityOfPage

Tags: url, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

Why is this happening?

[image: Screenshot of Google Structured Data Testing Tool’s output]

HTML shows:

```
<meta content='http://www.costumingdiary.com/2015/05/freddie-mercury-robe-francaise.html' itemprop='mainEntityOfPage' itemscope='itemscope'/>
```

Structured Data Testing Tool output shows:

```
http://www.costumingdiary.com/2015/05/freddie-mercury-robe-francaise.html#__sid=md3
```

Update: It looks like it has to do with my breadcrumb list. But still, why is it happening, and is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know where the fragment `#__sid=md3` is coming from, but as the SDTT had some quirks with `BreadcrumbList` in the past, it might also be a side effect of this.

But note that if you want to provide a URL as value for the `mainEntityOfPage` property, you [must use a `link` element instead of a `meta` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669):

```html
<link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="http://www.costumingdiary.com/2015/05/freddie-mercury-robe-francaise.html" />
```

([See examples for Microdata markup that creates an item value, instead of a URL value, for `mainEntityOfPage`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36117597/1591669).)

Answer (score 0):

If the URL you want to provide is unique you can use the `itemid` property. 
I was confronted with `mainEntityOfPage` by the tool after the latest update. And using Google's example I used the following code

```
<meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://blog.hompus.nl/2015/12/04/json-on-a-diet-how-to-shrink-your-dtos-part-2-skip-empty-collections/" />
```

And this show up correctly in the [Structured Data Testing Tool results for my blog](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=https%253A%252F%252Fblog.hompus.nl%252F)