# Microdata markup with 'mainEntityOfPage' for Google Article Rich Snippet

Tags: html, meta, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

The [Microdata example](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles#examples) of Google’s Article Rich Snippet contains this `meta` element with Schema.org’s `mainEntityOfPage` property:

> ```html
> <meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"  itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://google.com/article"/>
> ```

When checking it with the [Nu Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/), I get this error:

> Element `meta` is missing required attribute `content`.

Adding an empty `content` attribute seems to solve this error. Is it correct to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Nu Html Checker is correct, Google’s example is invalid. The `content` attribute is required if the `meta` element has an `itemprop` attribute.

From [WHATWG HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element) and also [HTML 5.1 (W3C Working Draft)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-html51-20160310/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element): "If […] `itemprop` is specified, then the `content` attribute must also be specified."
From the old [Microdata (W3C Note)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#content-models): "If a `meta` element has an `itemprop` attribute, […] the `content` attribute must be present."

Adding an empty `content` attribute makes it valid, but there are also other options.

---

Schema.org’s [`mainEntityOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) expects as value either a URL or a [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) item.

Google’s own documentation for the [recommended/required properties for their Article Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles#article_markup_properties) says that they expect a URL value, but their examples show how to create an item value.

All of the following solutions are fine according to the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/). (Some examples use the `itemid` attribute, which is, strictly speaking, [not yet allowed/defined](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/76) for the Schema.org vocabulary.)

### If you want to provide a URL value:

```
<link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://example.com/article" />
```

Straightforward.

This follows Google’s own recommendation, requires minimal markup, and works in the `head` as well as the `body`.

If you have a visible link, you can of course also use an `a` element.

### If you want to provide an item value:

As type you can use `CreativeWork` or any of its subtypes, like `WebPage`.

#### `div` element + `url` property

```
<div itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/article" /> 
</div>
```

This creates a `WebPage` item with a `url` property. It can only be used in the `body`.

If you have a visible link, you can of course also use an `a` element.

#### `meta` element with empty `content` attribute and `itemid`

```
<meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" content="" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://example.com/article" />
```

This is based on Google’s example, but with an empty `content` attribute to make it valid.

Note that Microdata parsers have to ignore the `content` attribute in that case, because the `itemscope` attribute is provided ([Microdata W3C Note](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values)/[WHATWG HTML Microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#values): "first matching case"). So the `itemprop` value will be an item, not a string.

This creates an empty item with an identifier. Works in the `head` as well as the `body`. It doesn’t allow to add properties directly to this `WebPage` item (you’d have to create another item with the same `itemid` value).

#### `div` element with `itemid`

```
<div itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://example.com/article">
</div>
```

This creates an empty item with an identifier. Instead of the `meta` example, it only works in the `body`, but therefore allows to add additional properties directly to this `WebPage` item.

### If you already have a `WebPage` item:

If you already provide a `WebPage` item on your page, e.g.,

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  </article>

</body>
```

you can make use of it via Microdata’s `itemref` attribute:

```
<body itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" id="this-page">

  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemref="this-page">
  </article>

</body>
```

combined with one of the methods described above, e.g., with `itemid` or a `url` property.

Note that you’d typically use [the inverse property `mainEntity`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467088/1591669) in such a case, but Google doesn’t document that they’d support it for the Article Rich Snippet, currently.