# Using 'meta' element instead of hiding an element with CSS?

Tags: html, meta, microdata

I made a Schema.org markup for blog post. I'm not sure if it is right way to combine `<meta>` with other tags, put `<meta>` inside of `<div>` and even put `<meta>` outside of `<head>`

```html
<article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
<meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">Article Title</h1>
    <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2017-10-23T11:40:36+00:00" content="2017-10-23T11:40:36+00:00" class="date">
        October 23rd, 2017
    </time>
    <time class="modified" itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2017-10-23T11:49:15+00:00" content="2017-10-23T11:49:15+00:00">
        October 23rd, 2017
    </time>
    <div itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="image" content="http://example.com/images/nick.jpg">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="nick">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com/authors/nick">
    </div>
    <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
        <div itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <meta itemprop="image" src="http://example.com/logo.png">
          <meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com">
          <meta itemprop="width" content="300">
          <meta itemprop="height" content="270">
        </div>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Publicher Name">
    </div>

    <meta itemprop="image" content="http://example.com/uploads/2017/10/Article-title.jpg">
</header>

<div class="entry-content jpibfi_container" itemprop="text">

</div>

</article>
```

The reason of such combine is simple. I just don't need to show some data to users, but I need to show it to SE and I know that hide non-style elements with `display:none` is a bad way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `meta` element is the right choice for data that is not visible. However, if the value is a URL, you [must use a `link` element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) instead of a `meta` element.

Issues with your `meta` elements:

- This is invalid, because the `content` attribute is required:

  > ```html
  > <meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  > ```

  [This answer describes alternatives for `mainEntityOfPage`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36117597/1591669)
- This is invalid, because `meta` can’t have a `src` attribute:

  > ```html
  > <meta itemprop="image" src="http://example.com/logo.png">
  > ```

  But as described above, you have to use a `link` element (with `href` attribute) anyway.