# What's the proper way to add Microdata (for Schema.org VideoObject) to a page in my Django app?

Tags: django, html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I'm followin the directions on Google which says

> Add schema.org markup directly to the HTML of your video page. The markup will not be visible to users and will not affect how your page looks

So I added the following to the top of my video html

```
<div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
  <h2>Video: <span itemprop="name">Title</span></h2>
  <meta itemprop="duration" content="T1M33S" />
  <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="thumbnail.jpg" />
  <meta itemprop="contentURL" content="http://www.example.com/video123.flv" />
  <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="http://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?video=123" />
  <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2011-07-05T08:00:00+08:00" />
  <meta itemprop="expires" content="2012-01-30T19:00:00+08:00" />
  <meta itemprop="height" content="400" />
  <meta itemprop="width" content="400" />
  <object ...>
    <param ...>
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ...>
  </object>
  <span itemprop="description">Video description</span>
</div>
```

soon as I did I saw a white block with the word title on top of it. I saw it and the directions said I wouldn't. Am I missing something? What's the proper way to do this?

EDIT: I'm using Django and heres my code

```
{% block content %}

<div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">

  <meta itemprop="duration" content="T1M33S" />
  <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="thumbnail.jpg" />
  <meta itemprop="contentURL" content="http://www.example.com/video123.flv" />
  <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="http://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?video=123" />
  <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2011-07-05T08:00:00+08:00" />
  <meta itemprop="expires" content="2012-01-30T19:00:00+08:00" />
  <!--<meta itemprop="height" content="400" />-->
  <!--<meta itemprop="width" content="400" />-->
  <object ...>
    <param ...>
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ...>
  </object>
  <span itemprop="description">Video description</span>
</div>

    <h2 id="detail-h1">
        {{ post.title }}
    </h2>

    {% if post.video %}
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe  src="{{post.video_path}}?autoplay=1&autohide=1" class="embed-responsive-item"
    frameborder="0" controls="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
    </div>
    {% else %}

    {% if post.image %}
        <img src='{{ post.image.url }}' class="img-responsive" width="730px" height="500"/>
    {% elif post.image_url %}
        <img src="{{post.image_url}}"  class="img-responsive">
    {% else %}
        <p>upload an image</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% endif %}


    <div style="margin-top: 10px; background: white; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        <span>
        <p style="float: left">
            {% if post.author %}
                Author: {{post.author}}
            {% endif %}
        </p>
        <p style="float: right" id="pub">
            {%if post.draft %}<span id="draft">Draft </span>{% endif %} Publicado: {{ post.publish|date }}
        </p>
        </span>

    <p class="tags" style="clear: both">Tags:

    {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'blog:post_list_by_tag' tag.slug %}">
            {{ tag.name }}
        </a>
            {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    </p>
```

Comment: culprit statement `<span itemprop="name">Title</span>`. add itemprop attribute to the text where you are writing your title

Comment: @user1533609 I still see the div though. Do I take all the meta tags out and the <span itemprop="name">Title</span> and the <span itemprop="description">Video description</span>. Even thought that's not what the directions say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted text (or the example) on [*Adding VideoObject to a video page*](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/schema#adding-videoobject-to-a-video-page) is misleading (or wrong).

It’s intended and correct that

```
<h2>Video: <span itemprop="name">Title</span></h2>
<span itemprop="description">Video description</span>
```

displays "Video: Title" and "Video description".

If you don’t want to display it, use a `meta` element instead:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="Title" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="Video description" />
```

But if possible, it’s of course preferable to use your existing markup instead of adding `meta`/`link` elements that duplicate the content.

If that’s not possible, there is really no reason to use Microdata, and you might want to use JSON-LD instead (which seems to be supported for [Google’s Video Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/videos), too).

---

By the way, Google’s example has three errors: If the value is a URL, the [`link` element must be used instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) of the `meta` element. So it should be:

```
<link itemprop="thumbnailUrl" href="thumbnail.jpg" />
<link itemprop="contentURL" href="http://www.example.com/video123.flv" />
<link itemprop="embedURL" href="http://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?video=123" />
```