# Adding Microdata for background images on simple HTML site

Tags: html, html-table, background-image, microdata

I am trying to enhance our old html site (webstore) with schema and am having some difficulties getting started. We have over 1,500 individual html product pages that I would like to start adding Schema to, so getting this correct to begin with is a must.

The biggest issue thus far is how to add the product image code as our site layout is table based with the main product image inserted as a background element. Most of the research examples I have found so far show different implementations, is this possible?

Here is a code example:

```
<TR>
   <TD COLSPAN=2><IMG SRC="images/spacer.gif" WIDTH=122 HEIGHT=10 ALT=""></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD COLSPAN=2><IMG SRC="images/spacer.gif" WIDTH=122 HEIGHT=18 ALT=""></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</td>

<td valign="top">
  <table width="599" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="images/LOTR/BKG_Hobbit-Sting-UC2892.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;">
  <tr>
  <td width="259" valign="top"><span class="style2 "><IMG SRC="images/spacer.gif" alt="" WIDTH=259 HEIGHT=150 border="0"><br></span>
    <table width="238" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><span class="style109 style31">The HOBBIT<br> BILBO'S STING SWORD</span><span class="style117"><br> <span class="style33">UC2892 United Cutlery</span></span></td>
      </tr>
```

From this code, I would like to highlight `images/LOTR/BKG_Hobbit-Sting-UC2892.jpg` as the product image via Schema.org.

I first tried adding the info to the `<HEAD>` section, but it does not check out correctly on Google's structured data testing tool:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="schema.org/Product">; <meta itemprop="image" content="images/LOTR/BKG_Hobbit-Sting-UC2892.jpg"></meta>
```

Also, testing in Bing Markup tester gives me the result:

> We are not seeing any markup on this page. Please ensure the markup has been implemented correctly.

Is it not okay to add the Schema data via `<div>` to the `head` area?

Also, should the image link be a complete URL `www.example.com/images/LOTR/BKG_Hobbit-Sting-UC2892.jpg`?

Comment: After lots of research, I've solved the issue by choosing to go with JSON-LD and adding all Microdata via a script. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `table` markup doesn’t seem to be very maintainable, and as the ([obsolete](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/obsolete.html#element-attrdef-body-background)) `background` attribute can’t be used for Microdata, the best way in your case would probably be to duplicate the content and mark it up with `meta`/`link` elements.

You can add this markup in the `head` or in the `body`, but you can’t use `div` in the `head`, so it’s easier to do it in the `body`.

So in the `body`, you could simply add this:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <link itemprop="image" href="images/LOTR/BKG_Hobbit-Sting-UC2892.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

You [have to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) use `link` instead of `meta` if the value is a URL. And this allows you to specify any kind of URL, absolute or relative (just like in the `a` element).

(Also note that neither `meta` nor `link` have a closing tag, so it’s `<meta>` or `<meta />`, but not `<meta></meta>`.)

That said, Microdata works best if you mark up your existing content, without duplicating it. If you would have to duplicate it, it [might work better](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328711/63183) for your to use JSON-LD instead of Microdata.

Comment: Agree, JSON-LD is in this case (old table layout) probably the better choise.

Comment: Thanks so much Unor, extremely helpful information! Here is what I settled on using JSON (no Bing usage):

`<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "STING SWORD of BILBO BAGGINS (UC2892)",
  "image": "https://...jpg",
  "description": "The Sting sword...",
  "manufacturer":"United Cutlery",
  "brand":"The Hobbit",
  "model":"UC2892",
  "url":"https://...html",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "price": "199.90",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  }
}
</script>`